# ServcieNow and DevOps Integration Question

Tags: devops, servicenow

What happens in a DevOps Release Pipeline if ServiceNow is unavailable?  Will DevOps recognize that ServiceNow is unavailable and allow you to proceed forward, even without an approval from ServiceNow?  Or is your Release Pipeline stuck until ServiceNow is available again?

Comment: For Azure DevOps?